# grep for exact word in a file containing "."

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

I have a file named "TestGrep" that contains content as shown below

```
#!/bin/bash

/ParentFolder/a @email1.com
/ParentFolder/b @email2.com
/ParentFolder/.a @email1.com
/ParentFolder/.b @email2.com
/ParentFolder/ @email3.com
```

I am using the below grep command

```
grep -Fw "/ParentFolder/" TestGrep
```

The output is

```
/ParentFolder/.a @email1.com
/ParentFolder/.b @email2.com
/ParentFolder/ @email3.com
```

It is somehow ignoring the dots in the TestGrep file. 
I want the output to be shown as below

```
/ParentFolder/ @email3.com
```

How can I query using grep command that would just check if the exact string match is done and return output as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Using `-E` option of `grep` here.

```
grep -E '/ParentFolder/\s+' Input_file
```

From `man grep` about `-E` option of grep:

> -E, --extended-regexp
>
> Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression

`\s+` means looks for spaces one or more occurrences.